# How to edit what is considered safe html for comments

Tags: comments, core-hacks

I'd like to be able to edit what is considered safe html for comments. I searched devotee but there's no addon making this easy to do so I guess I need to hack the core files. Where would one go to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd seen this somewhere!

In /system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Typography.php at around line 142 there are a couple of arrays for "safe" tags.

I'm not 100% sure if they appear anywhere else but it's worth having a look there and testing it out.

Comment: Yes that's the spot, really wish there was a way to set this in the CP, but this'll do for now.